# Why is my approach to the equation of time off by a constant?

Tags: astronomy, time

I'm trying to better understand the causes for the equation of time by deriving an approximation from first principles.

My naive approach, $EOT_{NAIVE}$, is to take the difference between the right ascension of the mean sun, $\alpha_M(t)$, and the right ascension of the "real" sun
$$EOT_{NAIVE}(t)=\langle\dot{\alpha }\rangle\cdot(t-t_0)-\alpha(t)$$
where $\alpha(t)$ is simply the "actual" position of the sun at time $t$ from ephemeris data (e.g. either of the RA values reported by [JPL HORIZONS](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), or a [similar source](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AstronomicalData.html)) and where $\langle\dot{\alpha }\rangle = 24/365.242$ and $t_0=t:\alpha_M(t_0)=0$.

To confirm that this is about right, I compare my result with what I get using the [USNO definition of GMST](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/GAST.php)
$$EOT_{GMST}(t)=GMST(t)-(t-t_{noon})-\alpha(t)$$
and with $EOT_{POLY}$, a standard polynomial expression from [Dershowitz & Reingold](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521702380) as [described](http://static.longnow.org/media/ClockPlans01.pdf) in The Clock of the Long Now documentation.

But the values I get for $EOT_{NAIVE}$ (blue dashed line) are consistently about $7.4$ minutes greater than these reference methods (exactly $7.4537$ for $EOT_{GMST}$, red line; and within a couple seconds of that for $EOT_{POLY}$, gray outline) give:

[image]

Surprisingly, I can fix this by simply changing $t_0$ from the date, $t_E$, on which the most recent vernal equinox occurred (2012-03-20T05:14:33Z) — [which I had assumed would give a "starting" RA of 0](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46700/2540) — to 2012-03-22T02:20:32.41Z, which brings my approximation (blue line) exactly in register with the GMST approach (gray band), and within a couple seconds of the polynomial approach (red line), as can be seen by taking the difference between the GMST approach (gray band) and each of these approaches (note the change of scale, this figure essentially takes the difference between $EOT_{GMST}$ and each of the plots in the first figure above, and "zooms in" on the gray band):

[image]

Why should changing the date in this way "fix" my approximation? Why doesn't my approximation work with $t_0=t_E$? Why does it work perfectly with a different date? Are the approaches I'm using as references ($EOT_{GMST}$ and $EOT_{POLY}$) the right ones for this kind of exploration?

---

Note that the reported RA of the sun at 2012-03-22T02:20:32.41Z is $0.1146^h$, and that the fit between $EOT_{GMST}$ and $EOT_{NAIVE}$ using that date is quite good (this figure zooms in further on the gray band in the second figure above):

[image]

Note also that despite the documentation for the ephemeris I use claiming that "light time delay is not included", the values I get match those from JPL's "airless apparent right ascension and declination of the target center with respect to the Earth's true-equator and the meridian containing the Earth's true equinox-of-date. Corrected for light-time, the gravitational deflection of light, stellar aberration, precession and nutation."

Comment: I deleted my answer, until I think further about the question. For the moment, I am not sure about it.

Comment: I think I got it, after the night sleep. I will give you a nice explanation tomorrow at the computer. Now I am tapping at a tiny, annoying touchscreen. The Mean Sun and the Apparent Sun cannot coincide at the V. Equinox but rather later because of the higher orbital speed the Earth has had from the Perihelion. It is a more subtle issue. A complete explanation with drawings and geometric arguments follows tomorrow or on monday.

Comment: @EduardoGuerras: A tip here is (of course) that solving $GMST(t)-(t-t_{noon})=0$ for $t$ gives 2012-03-22T02:20:32.5Z. But beyond that, I'm not sure.

Comment: @raxaco... : That trick seems to work because the RA variation of the Sun(s) is equivalent to ~1 deg per day, and the diurnal motion is ~1 deg every 4 minutes of time. Therefore, by changing that date in two days, you compensate adhoc for that 7.4 minutes (the RA change is retrograde).

Comment: @EduardoGuerras: But it tells us that $t_0$ is not in fact $t_E$ (independent of my naive approximation), right?

Comment: I don't have access to a real computer during the present weekend, but rather a tiny touchscreen, but I think I can give you an explanation on monday. The key is that, from the September Equinox to the Vernal Equinox, the Earth advances faster (and crosses the Perihelion point) and thus it reaches the Equinox too soon. The synchronisation of Mean and Apparent Sun must happen therefore later, in the middle of April. I will give a better explanation on monday.

Comment: Yes, you are right (I think). T0 is not Te, but nearly a month later. I is a surprise for mee, too...

Comment: Both the non-circular shape of our orbit and the ~23 deg inclination of our axis with respect to it, affect the shape of the EOT. The choice of the moment when the Mean Sun coincides with the Apparent Sun is a convention that only shifts the curve of the EOT up or down in the graphic but, since we want the Mean Sun to be as close as possible to the Apparent Sun for most of the year, the choice for T0 shifts the curve in such a way that leaves "as much curve" above 0 minutes as under 0 minutes.

Comment: You could choose to set the EOT to 0.0 in the Vernal eq, but then the EOT would be unbalanced by 15 min in the september eq, and the delay of the Mean Sun in other months would be even worse. So I think that the choice of t0 results essentially from fitting a horizontal line to the curve of the EOT, which results in t0 near april the 15th, but I would like to confirm this with a book.

Comment: Look for example at the residuals graphic you obtain. There is a periodic contribution there, and the distance between peaks is ~28 days. I think that it is due to the pull of the Moon...